# Multiple ListView Example

Tags: android, listview

I am working on an application where I have to display the list of songs in an Activity. I know I can do that using the ListView but actually the problem is that I want to display them in a Particular Manner.

I want to display them AS PER THE ARTISTS NAME. i.e. I WANT TO DISPLAY THE MULTIPLE SONGS OF A PARTICULAR ARTIST IN ONE ROW AND SIMILARLY THE OTHER BELOW THE ONE.

IN THE LIST VIEW FIRST NAME IS SUPPOSED TO BE THE NAME OF THE ARTIST THEN THE LIST OF HIS SONGS, AGAIN THE NAME OF THE SECOND ARTIST AND HIS LIST OF SONGS BELOW HIS NAME AND SO ON.

Can anyone please help me on this.

Thanks,
david

Comment: No need to shout, we can hear you just fine. :)

Comment: The sound that you are feeling Shout is my eagerness for what I am looking for my dear friend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically it is not a good idea to use multiple ListViews here. One method would be to use multiple rows in the ListView (and use different types for the rows, which ListView supports). The other method would be to inflate a whole LinearLayout/RelativeLayout as a view and put your children there. I would recommend the first one - multiple rows, different types.

Comment: Thanks for you answer, but I am not quite clear. If You have understood my question and if it is possible to do the same by the first option you have suggested than can you please give me an appropriate example!

Comment: Maybe it would help if you specify your problem more exactly - right now I understood that you want to create a ListView, sorted by artists, with all songs of an artist written under his name. This basically is no problem. Please avoid writing everything in upper case letters when you change your post - it's really hard to read. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Why not use expandable lists?

Check out: [ExpandableList1.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html)

[image]